# Organizing large c/c++ project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, project-organization

I'm trying to set up eclipse cdt (Indigo) for a large development project and need some help on organizing the eclipse workspace. The project is in its startup phase, parts are completed, but much more is to be developed. The project covers several products each consisting of several processes and a common set of libraries. The structure is about as follows:

```
top/
  Library/
    Math/
    Sys/
    Com/
  Include/
    Math/
    Sys/
    Com/
  Product/
    Prod1/
    Prod2/
```

I created a top workspace and want to use this for the whole project. I'm currently strugling with the Library and Include part. I need to create a new library called Err and a corresponding Err directory under the Include branch which is outside of the scope of the project created under the Library folder. Should I create this as a separate Err project in Eclipse? I tried this and the folder under Library was fine, but how then do I create the corresponding folder and files under the Include branch?

Is this the best way to organize the project or should I use one common project for all the libraries or divide the whole thing into several workspaces?

Comment: try QtCreator, in my experience Eclipse it's not conceived for large projects. an even better suggestion is "learn how to use a versioning tool such as git or subversion".

Comment: Qt is an alternative. Some type of VC is a must for large projects. We use StarTeam, but I do not see how that replaces a good IDE with editor, debugger etc.

Comment: well " a good IDE with editor, debugger etc. " it's not exactly a definition for Eclipse, first of all Eclipse doesn't even offer C/C++ support, CDT does, and CDT is just a plugin and in my experience is unreliable. I would consider other IDE for C/C++ devs and CDT is probably not what you want, valgrind is a good tool, gdb on linux is a good tools, CDT or Eclipse it's not ...